# I am struggling to remove entity using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{    
    var removeFromDb = db.StockQuantities.Take(stockToRemoveCount).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < removeFromDb.Count; i++)
    {
        db.Entry(removeFromDb[i]).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        db.Remove(removeFromDb[i]);

        stocktakes.Add(stockTake);
        stockTake.CurrentQty = stockTake.CapturedQty;

        db.Stocktakes.Update(stockTake);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, I have been stuck here for a long time now and I find errors or do not throw any errors when running the code, but it's not removing entities but adding works fine.

Comment: For a simple remove / delete just use the DbSet.RemoveRange: `var removeFromDb = db.StockQuantities.Take(stockToRemoveCount).ToList(); db.StockQuantities.RemoveRange(removeFromDb); db.SaveChanges();` If you want additional help you need to create an [mcve] and also explain *what* is actually occurring because "I have been stuck here a long time" is not descriptive of the actual problem.

Comment: Let's try this, but I think I have tried this, funny enough I am able to add without range but looping through the list.

Comment: @Igor nothing happens I have been debugging and stepping over checking if there's any errors.

Comment: The code after `Remove` looks suspicious. What is `stockTake`, where it comes from, what does it contain and does it have relationship with `StockQuantity`? It's possible that `db.Stocktakes.Update(stockTake);`  negates the remove operation in case the `stockTake` object contains references to the entities you are trying to delete.  We need to see the whole picture in order to help.

Comment: There is no relation between stockTake and StockQuantity, but I have noticed that if the records are more than 10 000 it does not remove but if less it works. It's weird hey.

Comment: @LonwaboMsingelwa That's quite important detail. If I recall correctly, 10 000 is the SqlServer limit for number of parameters in a SQL command. You might be hitting some EF Core implementation bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can choose between three options. The first is to just remove the entity from the DbSet

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{     
    var removeFromDb = 
       db.StockQuantities.Take(stockToRemoveCount).ToList();

   for (int i = 0; i < removeFromDb.Count; i++)
   {
       db.StockQuantities.Remove(removeFromDb[i]);
   }

   stockTake.CurrentQty = stockTake.CapturedQty;
   db.Stocktakes.Add(stockTake);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The second option would be to optimize the code using `RemoveRange` method. This should be the recommended approach since it will run `DetectChanges` on the dbSet only once, while the first approach will trigger `DetectChange` on each iteration.

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{     
    var removeFromDb = 
       db.StockQuantities.Take(stockToRemoveCount).ToList();
   
   db.StockQuantities.RemoveRange(removeFromDb);
   
   stockTake.CurrentQty = stockTake.CapturedQty;

   db.Stocktakes.Add(stockTake);
   
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

And the third option would be to mark the entity state as deleted

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{     
    var removeFromDb = 
       db.StockQuantities.Take(stockToRemoveCount).ToList();

   for (int i = 0; i < removeFromDb.Count; i++)
   {
       
       db.Entry(removeFromDb[i]).State = EntityState.Deleted;    
   }

   stockTake.CurrentQty = stockTake.CapturedQty;

   db.Entry(stockTake).State = EntityState.Added;
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I changed the data and all of sudden it worked, now I will have to check why. Thank you. Because I had tried exactly what you have shared.